# how to display certain data to kinect?

Tags: c#, kinect, gesture-recognition

I am using `kinect v2` `c#` to detect hand gesture. All my algo used is working right. The problem is that I want `kinect` to display only hand detected but not all of body and to give all points of the hand in a black background?

This is code that gets the points of contouring hand.

```
private void HandsController_HandsDetected(object sender, HandCollection e) {
        // Display the results!

        if (e.HandLeft != null)
        {
            point = e.HandLeft.ContourDepth;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for example you can write it like this

```
 // //left hand in front of left Shoulder
if (body.Joints[JointType.HandLeft].Position.Z < body.Joints[JointType.ElbowLeft].Position.Z && body.Joints[JointType.HandRight].Position.Y < body.Joints[JointType.SpineBase].Position.Y)
   {
      //Action here
   }
```

You can see a sample of how other libraries uses this code [here](https://github.com/LightBuzz/Vitruvius/blob/master/Kinect%20v2/WPF/LightBuzz.Vitruvius/Gestures/Segments/SwipeRightSegments.cs)

I also have a [tutorial](https://bingcheng45.wordpress.com/) on how to implements swipe gesture using [Vitruvius Library](https://vitruviuskinect.com/) do check them out! :D